# In ASP.Net 6, Controller class is raising an error when inherited from class Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-6.0

As you could see, in the image. I am not able to use the controller class as a base class to my `HomeController`.

[image]

Is there any update or should I change it to some other base controller?

Comment: I am not sure why it is showing `Controller`, change it to `ControllerBase`.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee No, he wants to return a `View`. `ControllerBase` is for WebAPI projects.

Comment: I have used ControllerBase instead of Controller. Then the issue arise that I could no longer use return View(). It is asking for using ViewResult.

Comment: Note: I am building an MVC project from the empty web application. When I create it from MVC, it doesn't give any problem. I think there is a dependency which I am not including.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your namespace ends with `.Controller`. This confuses the compiler to understand what class it wants to use. Rename your namespace and try again.

Comment: No it's not like that. The namespace is controller because it is inside a controller folder.

Comment: Yes, and that folder should be called `Controllers` to avoid this issue.

Comment: You were right, but it didn't happened just after renaming. I deleted the whole folder, created it again and then it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bhavesh that is because renaming did not update the namespace in your file. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your folder name from `Controller` to `Controllers`,and then change namespace from
`EmployeeManagement.Controller` to `EmployeeManagement.Controllers`.The name of your folder is conflicted with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller`.